# Racket 8.5 does not close primary and secondary windows

Tags: syntax-error, racket

I installed Racket 8.5 on my MacBook (MacOS Ventura Beta) and ran into a number of problems:

1. the application windows don't close on the cross, even the ones that are considered additional menus and shouldn't work that way anyway. [Add video](https://youtu.be/S319vsHj0LA)
2. In projects from my computer, the functions do not work correctly. And this error appears even if I move the author's code into my Racket in a clean project. For example, from a project downloaded from the Internet, where the author writes:

   ```
    empty-scene 100 100 "blue"
   ```

In his project everything works fine, this function is in the Racket documentation.
If I write this function in my project, Racket gives me an error;

```
empty-scene: expects only 2 arguments, but found 3
```

I tried to find information about this on the Internet, I reinstalled Racket and downloaded different versions of the program, but the problem persists.

Has anyone encountered similar problems? Are there any tips on how to fix it?

Comment: What `#lang` are you using? There's a few different ones with different versions of a `empty-scene` function.

Comment: @Shawn, I use Teaching Languages (Beginning Student) with 2htdp/image and universe Teachpacks

Comment: For your first question: these work fine on my machine running 11.6.7.  Perhaps something changed in the macOS beta? For the second: using the beginning student language with 2htdp/image teachpack then `(empty-scene 100 100 "blue")` will work fine in Racket 8.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea about the window thing: this doesn't happen on macOS 11 and I suspect is an artifact of running it on some beta version of macOS.

The arguments are because you're not in fact using `2htdp/image` but `htdp/image`, which provides a different version of `empty-scene`.  This is clear from looking at your video.

Also, please provide a description, *in text* of what is needed to reproduce problems like this: images and videos are just not a useful thing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm coming back with results! Your messages are confirmed. It turns out that everything was affected by the beta version of MacOS. After rolling back to Big Sur, both problems resolved.

Thanks so much Shawn and ignis-volens for looking at the problem from the outside and helping me solve it